# CUDA installation fails - unmet dependencies

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics, cuda

I am trying to install `CUDA` in `Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS` according to [this documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html) from nvidia.

I ran into trouble when I tried to install linux headers by the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

It raised an `Unmet dependencies` error.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcuinj64-9.1 : Depends: libcuda1 (>= 387.26) or
                           libcuda-9.1-1
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I tried

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

I got

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-compute-430_430.26-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ml.so', which is also in package nvidia-340 340.107-0ubuntu0.18.04.3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-compute-430_430.26-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The whole terminal output can be seen [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/L0p1sRKw).

This is the gpu I have

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GM204 [GeForce GTX 970]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:29 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

I am not sure where to go from here. Can anyone help?

Comment: Linux headers installation does not fail, as the output clearly says `linux-headers-4.15.0-64-generic is already the newest version (4.15.0-64.73).`, which is usually preinstalled. The documentation says to check for `linux-headers` before installing cuda, which you seem to have followed backwards. Something else must have caused the "unmet dependencies" error, which you'll need to undo. Also, the `nouveau` driver is up, while it should be blacklisted, and I see no nvidia driver installed.

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers  See what Nvidia drivers are offered in the Software and Updates/Additional Drivers.  If not current enough, add the graphics-drivers ppa and check again. Consider dropping back a CUDA version or two if the latest takes a driver only available from Intel -- you might get it to work, but with some effort.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have any proprietary nvidia-driver installed. From the ubuntu menu I went to `Software and Updates > Additional Drivers` and installed `nvidia-driver-430`.

```
foo@42:~$ sudo lshw -C display
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GM204 [GeForce GTX 970]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:30 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

The driver changed from `nouveau` to `nvidia`. It also installed `CUDA Version: 10.2`

```
foo@42:~$ nvidia-smi
Tue Oct  8 22:27:48 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 430.26       Driver Version: 430.26       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 970     Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   43C    P8    16W / 200W |    191MiB /  4039MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      4953      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            16MiB |
|    0      4998      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          51MiB |
|    0      5151      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            79MiB |
|    0      5392      G   ...ervice-request-channel-token=1831114496    39MiB |
```